# Windows Explorer exact string search does not work with hyphens

Tags: windows-explorer, search

It looks like Explorer search [treats quotation marks](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/searching-windows-explorer-10-file-contents-for/aa7e860e-7e7a-4fc0-a43a-362380b6b114?auth=1) like Google search's [exact match](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) where a search for "foo bar" ignores results like "**bar** the **foo**" so you only get results like "the **foo bar**."

But having hyphens like `foo-bar` confuses it.

For example, in a folder with these contents:

[image]

Filename-only search does not work correctly:

[image]

Nor does contents-only search:

[image]

How can I use Windows Explorer search to behave consistently? Abandon it for the Command Prompt?

Comment: You might try a third-party tool, such as indexed DocFetcher, or real-time Agent Ransack. Both offer regexp for filenames, but AgentRansack uses regexp (and other criteria) for searching contents.

Answer (score 3):

For filenames, [Query Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators) can offer some help:
`name:~~"foo-bar"`
should give you the results you want:
[image]

But content search doesn't seem as well behaved. Created two files, one with content "foo-bar", the other with content "foo bar". The following attempts returned both files:

```
content:"foo-bar"
content:$$"foo-bar"
```

While `content:~~"foo-bar"` returned none!

So, for accurae content searching, I would go with **PowerShell** and the [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) cmdlet:

[image]

There's definitely a learning-curve, but with support for regular expressions, it's a very powerful tool.